# Multiple Google Maps via Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add multiple Google Maps within WordPress functions.php, yet only the last map is showing.

How can I show multiple maps?
Is it possible to create a shortcode loop?

I've tried to replace var "map" with an $arg or a random ID without success.

```
add_shortcode( 'map', 'gmaps_map' );
function gmaps_map( $args ) {

        $id = substr( sha1( "Google Map" . time() ), rand( 2, 10 ), rand( 5, 8 ) );
    ob_start();

    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'lat'    => '49',
        'lng'    => '9',
        'zoom'   => '12',
        'height' => '300px',
        'id' => '0'
    ), $args, 'map' );

    ?>
    <div class='map' style='height:<?php echo $args['height'] ?>;' id='map-<?php echo $id ?>'></div> 

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var <?php echo $args['id'] ?>;
    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-<?php echo $id ?>'), {
        center: {lat: <?php echo $args['lat'] ?>, lng: <?php echo $args['lng'] ?>},
        zoom: <?php echo $args['zoom'] ?>

      });

      var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/marker.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(64,64));

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: <?php echo $args['lat'] ?>, lng: <?php echo $args['lng'] ?>},
        map: map,
        icon: image, // null = default icon
        animation:  google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      });

    }
    </script>

    <?php
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'gmaps_enqueue_assets' );
function gmaps_enqueue_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 
      'google-maps', 
      '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap', 
      array(),
      '1.0', 
      true 
    );
}
```

Comment: What did you try to debug? Any error in your JS console? What does `id='map-<?php echo $id ?>'` print if you inspect the output HTML? Nobody can/will help you with so little info.

Comment: Thank you. The id is echoed properly.
The problem was with initMap, see below.

Answer (score 0):

This works within a separate js file (not within functions.php shortcode)

```
function initMap(id, lang, long) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), {
      center: {lat: lang, lng: long},
      zoom: 13

    });

    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("/images/marker.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(64,64));

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: lang, lng: long},
      map: map,
      icon: image, // null = default icon
      animation:  google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });

  }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.map').each(function() {
        initMap($(this).attr('id'), parseFloat($(this).data('lat')), parseFloat($(this).data('lng')));
    });
});
```